# Jms serializer annotations as yaml file

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I've been working on `User` class inherited from `BaseUser` of `FOSUserBundle`, so I've faced a problem. I need to set up serialization for my `User` but JMS serializer serializes all properties of `BaseUser`.
Solution that I found was to create my own annotation for `BaseUser` and store it in yaml file, but I don't know how exactly should I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMSSerializerBundle by default use your `AcmeBundle/Resources/config/serializer` directory to fetch all metadata that are declared in `yml` or `xml` files. You need to create file with name `Entity.User.yml` to point serializer to use your `AcmeBundle/Entity/User` entity.

If you need to define metadata for third party bundles (base entities) you can define custom path for fetching metadata in `config.yml`:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            FOSUB:
                namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
                path: %kernel.root_dir%/serializer/FOSUB
```

In this case you need to locate your metadata file in `%kernel.root_dir%/serializer/FOSUB` directory with name like `Model.User.yml`.

Comment: I can't find any examples of what Model.User.yml might look like.

Comment: @Henry, configuration example for yaml format you can find in documentation of JMSSerializer: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference