# JMSSerializer required metadata file?

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have a simple question with JMSSerializer:
Are metadata config files required or the metadata can be set only with annotation ?

Thanks.

Comment: and if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670813/jms-serializer-annotations-as-yaml-file) was linked in your question and the reason why it didn't work... that is called effort if posted in your question. So.. tell us what you tried and didn't work...

Comment: I try to understand why JMSSerializer doesn't serialize my entities, I have an empty json. I don't set any metadata config files.